# Searching and matching characters between 2 columns on 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, search

I have 2 worksheets (Worksheet 1 & Worksheet 2). I am trying to searching the characters in column A on Worksheet 1 and see if those characters exist in Column A on Worksheet 2. Please note that these characters are not fixed, so characters may be added, removed, or changed. If they exists in Worksheet 2, then I would bold the characters in Worksheet 1 to the corresponding cell.

**Worksheet 1**

*Column A*

```
Jack
James
Peter
Angel
```

**Worksheet 2**

*Column A*

```
Jack ate an apple.
Peter flies a kite.
Henry wakes up for work.
James went to school.
```

My approach to this so far is using For loops and if-else statements. I was thinking about using InStr to find the characters within those sentence in Worksheet 2.

```
Dim StartNum As Integer
Dim EndNum As Integer
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

EndNum =

For StartNum = 1 To EndNum
    If rng1.Value = InStr(rng2.Value) Then _
        rng1.font.Bold = True
End If
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have tried already?  This will help the community get you exactly what you need.

Comment: I'm unclear on what you mean by *bold the characters in Worksheet 1 to the corresponding cell*. If you supplied some code (working or not), your intentions would be easier to grasp.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know @daytonrazorback I just posted the code that I have started.

Comment: For example, Since Jack is founded in Worksheet 2 in the sentence "Jack ate an apple." Jack in Worksheet 1 will be bolded. Hopefully this makes sense @Jeeped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all of column A on worksheet 1 with A1 as the *active cell*. Choose Home ► Conditional Formatting ► New Rule* and when the **New Formatting Rule* dialog appears, choose *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* then supply the following in the *Format values where this formula is true:* text box.

```
 =isnumber(match("*"&A1&"*", 'Worksheet 2'!A:A, 0))
```

Click <kbd>Format</kbd> and select *Bold* from the *Font* tab. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> once to accept the formatting and then <kbd>OK</kbd> again to create the new rule.

I added a few non-matching names to **Worksheet 1** and topped up the formatting change with a bold blue font for these results.

[image: cONDITIONAL fORMATTING WITH tEXT WITHIN tEXT]

Answer (score 0):

A simple macro would do the work for you. Suppose you have a Sheet with Names and another with Sentences. So here is a small code:

```
Sub HighlightFound()
Dim searchRange As Range
Set searchRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sentences").Range("A:A")

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Names").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    If Not searchRange.Find(ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Font.Bold = True
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=1).Select
Loop
```

End Sub

**HAPPY VBA CODING!!!**

Comment: The code snippet is tested so go ahead test in your workbook. :)

Comment: if it has served your purpose, just vote for the answer so that other people with same need can use my solution.